# How do I revert to an alternate version of a package on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, downgrade

I upgraded to an alpha version of a package in a PPA and would now like to revert back to the official version in the Ubuntu universe. What steps do I need to take?

**Edit:** The question originally read "How do I revert to a **previous** version of a package on Ubuntu?". I've changed it to more accurately reflect the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line:

> sudo apt-get remove package_name
>
> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list -> comment out the ppa providing the new package
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install package_name

GUI:

- start Synaptic Package Manager
- search for your package, click on it and select mark for removal
- click apply
- go to Settings > Repositories > Third Party Software and uncheck the PPA providing the new packge
- Click Close, and then Reload
- search for the package and reinstall it.

Optionally, you can re-enable the PPA after reverting to the Ubuntu default package

Answer (score 6):

Christian's [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/20830/how-do-i-revert-to-a-previous-version-of-a-package-on-ubuntu/20836#20836) works fine when you want to get rid of the PPA.

I found another way to do this that leaves the PPA versions available as options for the future.

1. Use **apt-cache showpkg** to list the candidate versions available:

   > sudo apt-cache showpkg  mpd
2. Explicitly install the version you want, in the format *"package=version"*

   > sudo apt-get install mpd=0.14.2-3ubuntu2

Comment: apt-cache doesn't require sudo.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/ppa-purge). It disables the PPA and reverts your system back to the official Ubuntu packages.

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa_name
```

And you're done !

Installation : `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` (or [apturl install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ppa-purge))
If you're not using Ubuntu 10.10 you may need to install it from a ppa, webup8 for example :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

The package is also included in the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers) repository and I successfully used it after testing the latest Xorg packages.

There is a blog post on [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/ppa-purge-added-to-official-ubuntu-1010.html).

Answer (score 0):

Search for your package on http://packages.ubuntu.com/

And download a previous version and `sudo dpkg -i` it.